# Limitations with NSString Initwithformat:arguments:

Tags: objective-c, ios, string, nsstring

I'm trying to use

```
NSString *iosString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%ls = %ls" arguments:argListSave];
```

The problem is that `initWithFormat` does not support `%ls`, and `argListSave` contain `wchar_t*`, how can I get around this limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wchar_t *ws1 = va_arg(argListSave, wchar_t *);
wchar_t *ws2 = va_arg(argListSave, wchar_t *);

NSString *s1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:ws1 length:wstrlen(ws1)];
NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:ws2 length:wstrlen(ws2)];

NSString *iosString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ = %@", s1, s2];
[s1 release];
[s2 release];
```

Edit: it seems that the two character types are of different size. You may thus want to implement an strcpy-like conversion function like this:

```
unichar *wchar_to_unichar(unichar *result, wchar_t *input)
{
    while (*input)
    {
        *result++ = *input++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Edit 2: seems this is still not good. As @Jonathan Grinspan pointed out, you have to consider UTF32 code points as well and use

```
initWithBytes:length:encoding:
```

with NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding on Intel macs and NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding on PowerPC Macs (length being thr string length in bytes, not characters).

Comment: What if the argListSave contains unicode utf-8 characters? Does this still apply?

Comment: @mskw then no. But then it's no longer a wchar_t * and you can simply use %s then.

Comment: I tried the above code, initWithCharacters uses const unichar *, as in - (id)initWithCharacters:(const unichar *)characters length:(NSUInteger)length   and the complier complaints.

Comment: This won't work! On Mac/iOS, `wchar_t` is 32 bits wide, but `unichar` is only 16 bits wide.

Comment: Hm, strange. But then basically the entire answer makes no sense, does it?

Comment: @H2CO3: The conversion you've supplied is *still* wrong. `unichar` represents a UTF-16 code point. `wchar_t` on Mac OS X/iOS represents a UTF-32 code point. The former cannot be converted to the latter without taking into account surrogate pairs.

Comment: What you really want is `[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: theWideString length:sizeof(wchar_t) * wcslen(theWideString) encoding: NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding]`. Note that this assumes the system is little-endian. On a big-endian system (e.g. PowerPC Mac), substitute `NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding`.) `NSUTF32StringEncoding` will not always work correctly as it expects a BOM character that might be missing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14655/discussion-between-h2co3-and-jonathan-grynspan)

Comment: This is awesome, as I thought i went nuts trying to get it to work. Let me try it out.